# Update item in DataSet

Tags: vue.js

I can't find a way to update an item of my item array.

What I want to do is to remove an item before pushing it into the list if this item already exists. What I don't want to do is to iterate through all items to find witch one i have to delete, if there is one.

I tryied to use a watcher :

```
watch: {
    list: function (list, oldList) {     
        }
}
```

but since I get the old and new list, I still need to iterate.

Checking the documentation I found a `$remove` method that :

> will search for that value in the array and remove the first occurrence.

So I tryied `this.list.$remove(item.Id)` but it doesn't work.

I tryied to use `JQuery.grep()` to select the right item but it needs to iterate so, that's a no.

Is there any way in vue.js to perform what I am trying to do ?

**EDIT**

I can select the right item to delete with the `$eval` method :

```
var expr = "list | filterBy " + value.Id + " in 'Id'";
var item = this.$eval(expr);
this.list.$remove(item);
```

But now that I have my item, the `$remove` method seems to not do it's job. Am I using it wrong or something ?

Comment: I don't think is possible without iterate the array

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois You should undelete [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37275633/) question. I think I have a solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't `this.list.$remove(item)` enough? Vue will search array for you and remove proper item. Actually that is exactly what you are doing with `$eval` method.